# How to Make .htaccess search by allow mod_rewrite as query string and page number?

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, mod-rewrite

My original file is a PHP page named `search.php`.

Normally, the search function will be:

`mydomain.com/search.php cid=&type=search&q=keyword+text&page=2`

However, is it possible to rewrite it to `mydomain.com/all.html?q=keyword+text&page=[1-anypage]`?

I tried to put this code into .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^all.html?q=([^.*]+)&p=([0-9]+)$ search.php?cid=&type=search&q=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

but something went wrong.

Please help me find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible but you can't match against  query string in pattern of a RewriteRule,  you will need to use `RewriteCond` directive  to check `%{QUERY_STRING}` something  like the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+)&page=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^all\.html$ /search.php?cid=&type=search&q=%1page=%2 [L]
```